# Determining whether tensors are being tf.casted inside some tensorflow code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, casting

Is it possible to determine programmatically whether executing some tensorflow code involves casting any tensors e.g. from tf.float32 to tf.float64? I've recently removed some code that did this unnecessarily in a complex function and would like to test it (as well as confirm that there are no other instances to fix).

For example, the test would check that calling `bad_double` with a float32 involves a cast, but calling `good_double` doesn't:

```py
def bad_double(x: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
    return tf.cast(tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.float64) * 2, x.dtype)
    
def good_double(x: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
    return x * 2
```